# Pythonic ways to avoid Pointers

Tags: python, pointers, coding-style

Assume we have an object `a` and we want modify data which is structures like this

`a.substructure1.subsubstructure1.name_of_the_data1`

and this

`a.substructure2.subsubstructure2.name_of_the_data2`

To access this structure we call an external method `get_the_data_shortcut(a)` which is heavily parameterized (for example the parameter  `subsstructure` specifies which substructure to return). This seems very redundant but there is a very good default setting for all these parameter which makes sense. Also, this function will return another branch of data if the default branch is not available.

How do I modify `get_the_data_shortcut(a)` ?

```
b = get_the_data_shortcut(a)
b = b + 1
```

Then, `get_the_data_shortcut(a)` is unchanged because well Python is not Java.

Do I need a setter? Mostly, this is not my code and written by people who write pythonic code, and I am trying to keep up with those standards.

Comment: The usual Python way would be to do something like `b = a.substructure1.subsubstructure1; b.name_of_the_data1 += 1`. But maybe you should write a [mcve] so we have something more tangible to discuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered changing the object b refers to won't modify the a object (or its substructures). If you want to do this you will need a method similar to your get_the_data_shortcut(a). Namely a

```
set_the_data_shortcut(a, newvalue)
```

Alternatively you could have a method which would return the substructure the value was stored in and manipulate that..

```
# returns a.substructure2.subsubstructure2 
#          or a.substructure1.subsubstructure1 based on the value of kind
substruct = get_the_substructure(a, kind)
substruct.name_of_data1 += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Python uses reference types, just like java.
However, when you do

```
b = b + 1
```

you are not updating the object you have. Instead, you are creating a new object and assigning it to the variable `b`.

If you want to update the value of `b` in the data structure, you should follow your suggestion and write a setter for the data structure.